# Hack public static fields of a running .net application when you have not the source code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, static-methods

I'm using public static fields in my c# application:

Is is possible for someone who **has not the source code** of the app (**obfuscated**) to change those fields at application **runtime**? (for example using the attach feature of the VS)

Comment: If they're public, someone can reference your app and do whatever they want to the fields.  Don't make them public if you don't want people accessing them.  But that's an entirely different question....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they don't even need to attach a debugger. Because the fields are public all someone needs to do is add your program as a reference to it then they can just call your Main function from theirs and they can manipulate all public variables all they want.

Comment: will internal modifier protect them?

Comment: From this specific case, yes, but if someone figures out what the name of the field is they can just use reflection to access any internal, protected, or private field.

Comment: even if the assembly is obfuscated?

Comment: Yes, all obfuscating does is make the name unreadable. If they figure out what the field does they don't need to know what the name is, they can just use the obfuscated name in the reflection.

Answer (score 0):

While I've never personally tried this, I would imagine you could decompile the DLL using .NET Reflector, then debug against the running process with the newly constructed "source code".

Answer (score 0):

Using something like [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) and attaching a debugger, it should be possible. At least it won't be easy due to obfuscation.

Hope it helps!